# How to start and end a line with dot through CAShapeLayer in Swift 5.0

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

How to start and end a line with a dot as shown in below image:

[image]

I have manage drawing circle but I don't know how to add dot at start and end of line:

```
let arcCenter = CGPoint(x: vwCircle.frame.width / 2,
                        y: vwCircle.frame.height / 2)

let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter,
                                 radius: 15,
                             startAngle: 0,
                               endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi),
                              clockwise: true)

shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer!.path = circlePath.cgPath

//change the fill color
shapeLayer!.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
//you can change the stroke color
shapeLayer!.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
//you can change the line width
shapeLayer!.lineWidth = 3.0

vwCircle.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer!)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this (and, therefore, the way I'd do it) is simply to use more shape layers. For each dot, make a shape layer whose shape is a dot at the center. Then add that layer and give it a rotation transform to the angle where you want it to go followed by a translation transform out to the radius of the circle.

[image]

So, that drawing is actually three shape layers: the outer circle, one dot, and the other dot. Here's how the dot at the top was created:

```
let angle : CGFloat = .pi * 2 * 3 / 4
// ...
let lay = CAShapeLayer()
lay.frame = circleLayer.bounds
lay.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
lay.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
let dot = UIBezierPath(
    arcCenter: CGPoint(x: circleLayer.bounds.midX, y: circleLayer.bounds.midY), 
    radius: 3, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi*2.0, clockwise: true)
lay.path = dot.cgPath
circleLayer.addSublayer(lay)
// and now add the transform
lay.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0, 0, 1)
lay.transform = CATransform3DTranslate(lay.transform, circleRadius, 0, 0)
```

By changing the value `.pi * 2 * 3 / 4`, you can place the dot anywhere you like on the circle.